# Jest Test Issues with SQLite Database in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this function that works perfectly when executed alongside the main program, but the Jest test does not receive the appropriate outputs. I've tried everything, including putting the function itself and creating the SQLite database within the test file, but nothing has worked. I suspect that Jest is not executing the proper connection with the database. Can someone help me?

```
async function verifyGroupInDB(id, database = db) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = [];
        const groupId = id;
        database.all('SELECT group_Id FROM random_tabçe WHERE group_Id = ? LIMIT 1', groupId, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                rows.forEach(row => {
                    result.push(row.group_Id);
                });
                resolve(result.length > 0);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The console does not output any type of error, only the incorrect output (in this case, when true is expected, it returns false).

My test file:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const {verifyGroupInDB} = require('../db');

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./databaserandomname.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err.message);

  console.log("connection with sqlite established")
})


describe('verifyGroupInDB', () => {
  test('return true if the group exists in the database', async () => {
    const id = 4;
    const result = await verifyGroupInDB(id,db);
    console.log(result)
    expect(result).toBe(true);
  });

  test('return false if id don't exists in the database', async () => {
    const id = 999;
    const result = await verifyGroupInDB(id,db);
    expect(result).toBe(false);
  });


});
```

Obviously, I made sure that the ID exists.